# how to unpack FIrebaseUser from parcelable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, parcel

So I have a code that includes a User class that contains FirebaseUser. Now I am trying to pass the class through Intent but, although FirebaseUser has a method to write to the parcel, it doesn't have a static Creator so I can't find a method to unpack from the parcel.

here is the writeToParcel method of my class.

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    this.user.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeInt(this.Role);
    dest.writeString(this.Address);
    dest.writeString(this.phoneNumber);
}
```

So after getting no answers in almost a month I chose to switch over to this constructor which is not the best way but it is enough.

```
    protected User(Parcel in) {
        this.user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        this.Role = in.readInt();
        this.Address = in.readString();
        this.phoneNumber = in.readString();
        this.docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(in.readString());
    }
```

But if someone finds an answer to my question it would be amazing.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to pass the object to the Intent.

Comment: which code? the putExtra to intent? the writeToParcel(which is above) or the new Constructor(which I don't know how to create because of the problem i mentioned)?